Ansible Vault: How to access vault keys dynamically
I inherited a project where all database users have the same password (bad!). This password is stored in an Ansible Vault (good). I want to modify the roles so that each user has a unique password stored in the vault.
Current Vault:
---
DB_USER: secretpass

Current Vars:
mysql_remote_users_enabled:
  - user: user1
    host: ip_address1
  - user: user2
    host: ip_address2

Current Task:
- name: "mysql remote users present"
  mysql_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ mysql_root_passwd }}"
    name: "{{ remote_user.user }}"
    host: "{{ remote_user.host }}"
    password: "{{ DB_PASS }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    "{{ mysql_remote_users_enabled }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: remote_user

How can I store a unique password for each user in the vault and access these vault variables dynamically in my Ansible task?

You could do the encryption at the value level rather than at a file level, then have a {{ remote_user.password }}. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/vault_guide/vault_encrypting_content.html#encrypting-content-with-ansible-vault

Okay, thats a straightforward solutions but not dynamic as I have to access each password by hand. Would prefer a dynamic approach.

What do you mean by 'I have to access each password by hand'?

In the password field, I have to access DB_USER1_PASS and DB_USER2_PASS. I wonder how to achieve this using the username already listed in the vars.

Why would you? Store the encrypted value in the dictionaries of mysql_remote_users_enabled right away.

Ok. But this is not a real answer to my question, as this should use the vault where I have stored all other secrets, too.

So, once again: why? You have still not raised any practical reason for it.

Because it might be interesting how this could be done. Not every information can be stored encrypted directly. This applies to mysql_user only but maybe not for other secrets. I just want to know how this might be done.

Fair enough. You couldn't probably guess it but accessing a variable dynamically is unrelated to the fact it is vaulted of not, so those are, in the end two different subject matter.

might be less practical, but i use simple env file to keep separate passwords. in this way anyone in the team can dynamically use the env file without registering each password to ansible vault , at least it saves some production time~

The more practical way of doing it is to do the encryption at the value level:
## The password for those two vaulted value is `foobar`
mysql_remote_users_enabled:
  - user: user1
    host: ip_address1
    password: !vault |
      $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
      3633353366323334653265343961373732346331363565336139326136623
      1343661633131323938383465396565363364333237383436323139633232
      3336310a62316362623361393730343765346234343266386165663038636
      2656562363834653534376565653335623432646366646433363735333034
      313662646166620a653965646263366133336362376332333435653932313
      2613664353533326230
  - user: user2
    host: ip_address2
    password: !vault |
      $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
      3538333130323831313136653338316261643832336237646639646264343
      5303832306663663936383637326233643733316565323133356536613432
      6530640a31373161323238663062623035346338613766653239633432393
      2396666666437336235316334353463643737356262313662646339633831
      393833646162630a656636636331633532396532373863666366636162663
      2303366666538663962

Then, use it in the task:
- name: MySQL remote users
  mysql_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ mysql_root_passwd }}"
    name: "{{ remote_user.user }}"
    host: "{{ remote_user.host }}"
    password: "{{ remote_user.password }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ mysql_remote_users_enabled }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: remote_user


To vault a single value, use the encrypt_string command of ansible-vault:
# For example to encrypt `foo`
$ ansible-vault encrypt_string 'foo'
New Vault password: 
Confirm New Vault password: 
Encryption successful
!vault |
      $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
      3633353366323334653265343961373732346331363565336139326136623
      1343661633131323938383465396565363364333237383436323139633232
      3336310a62316362623361393730343765346234343266386165663038636
      2656562363834653534376565653335623432646366646433363735333034
      313662646166620a653965646263366133336362376332333435653932313
      2613664353533326230

Note: you can also use it with a different vault ID or a password files, for more options see the documentation, or the --help of ansible-vault.

As for accessing a variable dynamically, this is unrelated to vaulting, the way to access a dynamic variable, vaulted or not, is to use the vars lookup.
For example:
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('vars', 'DB_' ~ remote_user.user | upper ~ '_PASS') }}"
  vars:
    remote_user:
      user: user1
    DB_USER1_PASS: foobar

Would yield
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: foobar


How do you generate these vault entries?

@Powerriegel That's edited in the answer, the way to access a variable dynamically (no matter if the variable is vaulted or not) is also.

Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.

There are many options:

Put the passwords into the files. For example,

shell> cat vault/user1@ip_address1 
user1_ip1_passwd

shell cat vault/user2@ip_address2 
user2_ip2_passwd

shell> cat vault/user3@ip_address3 
user3_ip3_passwd

Encrypt the files.
Then, the below play will read the files on demand
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    mysql_remote_users_enabled:
      - {user: user1, host: ip_address1}
      - {user: user2, host: ip_address2}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          name: {{ item.user }}
          host: {{ item.host }}
          password: {{ DB_PASS }}
      loop: "{{ mysql_remote_users_enabled }}"
      vars:
        file: "vault/{{ item.user }}@{{ item.host }}"
        DB_PASS: "{{ lookup('file', file) }}"

gives (abridged)
ok: [localhost] => (item={'user': 'user1', 'host': 'ip_address1'}) => 
  msg: |-
    name: user1
    host: ip_address1
    password: user1_ip1_passwd
ok: [localhost] => (item={'user': 'user2', 'host': 'ip_address2'}) => 
  msg: |-
    name: user2
    host: ip_address2
    password: user2_ip2_passwd


The next option is to put the passwords into a dictionary. There are plenty of options on how to create it and where to put it. Make your choice, probably on the source of the passwords. For example,

shell> cat group_vars/all/db_pass.yml 
db_pass:
  user1@ip_address1: user1_ip1_passwd
  user2@ip_address2: user2_ip2_passwd
  user3@ip_address3: user3_ip3_passwd

Encrypt the file.
Then, the below play gives the same result
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    mysql_remote_users_enabled:
      - {user: user1, host: ip_address1}
      - {user: user2, host: ip_address2}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          name: {{ item.user }}
          host: {{ item.host }}
          password: {{ DB_PASS }}
      loop: "{{ mysql_remote_users_enabled }}"
      vars:
        idx: "{{ item.user }}@{{ item.host }}"
        DB_PASS: "{{ db_pass[idx] }}"


Use passwordstore

